# Android ADT version required 20.0.0 and above

Tags: android, adt

Yesterday I tried to install titanium appcelerator and in the process I edited some of the android sdk installations Now I have updated my android sdk to rev 20. But when i start eclipse i get an error that sdk requires version 20.0.0 or above. I tried to install by using eclipse->help->check for updates-> but again the installation doesn't work claiming that required items could not be found. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better to Download Latest Eclipse Setup Juno http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/ open this link and download this version
**Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers**

Answer (score 15):

Goto <kbd>Help</kbd> → <kbd>Install New Software</kbd>.

In there you click the `work with:` dropdown and select your android adt link.

Then it will show the list of things to install choose it click next.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

I also got the same error and I solved it from updating adt.
 
Go to : <kbd>Eclipse</kbd> → <kbd>Help</kbd> → <kbd>Install New Software</kbd>
 and click the `work with` drop down and select  android adt link that you have used previously. It looks like this :

> android ADT - https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/.

Tick the developers tools check box and click next. If you have already installed some of them, then eclipse will notify you.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error, I solved this by updating the Android SDK tools and Android SDK platform tools.
From <kbd>Eclipse</kbd> → <kbd>Window</kbd> → <kbd>Android SDK Manager</kbd>, then Update <kbd>Tools</kbd> → <kbd>Android SDK Tools</kbd>
 and Android SDK platform tools packages. After this restart the eclipse and then update the ADT again. (<kbd>Help</kbd> → <kbd>Check for new Updates</kbd>).

Comment: I tried doing it but as soon as i click on the android sdk and avd manager it says sdk manager preferences are not set up

Comment: The SDK path mentioned in Window --> Preferences --> Android is correct?

Answer (score 1):

What I did was to uninstall the latest ADT and go back to a previous ADT. It worked.

Go to <kbd>Help</kbd> → <kbd>Install New Software</kbd> - look for the already installed hyperlink. Uninstall all ADT's. Restart Eclipse and it will tell you the ADT you need for the revision tools you have. Download this ADT and install it manually. It should at least work.

Answer (score 1):

This is the best and quick solution:

**Open SDK manager -> Packages menu -> Reload**

Answer (score 0):

if You have to update ADT 20.0 otherwise it's not work and also not list the Number of SDK install.
i have that problem and fix by updating ADT 20.0 , also Good User Interface.

Answer (score 0):

I suspected that something was wrong with my configuration, as I shouldn't have to suddenly update the ADT when everything had been previously working.

BTW, I got this with "Android ADT version required 21.0.0 and above".

To fix it, I:

1. Reinstalled eclipse (which is quite easy, as the zip was still in my Downloads, so I just deleted my eclipse directory and unzip the original again - eclipse doesn't use the registry)
2. Created a "hello_world" java app, in eclipse, to test that (fixing any problems with the standard searches");
3. Created a "hello_world" Android app to test that (fixing any problems with the standard searches).
4. Reverted my project files to the last known working version,
5. Imported my project, and fixed an problems, etc...

About an hour's work. No downloads (assuming you've still got your eclipse zip), no update to the ADT, and no obscure problems which I haven't faced before.

This person (http://kcwebprogrammers.blogspot.com.au/2012/07/android-sdk-eclipse-hell.html) recommends a complete re-install, but it seems that a partial restoration may work.

Answer (score 0):

I too had the same problem. I resolved it by doing the following in Eclipse:

Go to Help -> Check for Updates -> Install all the Updates available.
 only check on Android Development Tools then press next and accept install it :)

Mohamed Safwat

Helwan Uni

eng.mohamedsafwat@yahoo.com

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse (ADT)

> Help -->  Install New Software --->  Work with -->  Android Developer
>   Tools Update Site - http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

Select all of the updates you want to install and UNCHECK option "Contact all update sites during install to find required software". After that everything should install as it is mentioned to be.

Comment: If you can post an *identical* answer to several questions it's a sign that the questions are duplicates. You should be flagging the questions as such rather than posting answers.